# Error passing function onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have two files. A list Component and a Single Item Component. In my app, the user can select multiples items. Then I create an state element in "list" "items" and my idea is that when the user make click on the item button, the list element notify to List Component and save the item in Items array from "list".

I have the next code

List.jsx:

```
registrarItems(data,item){
        console.log(data,"aqui 1 con",item);
        let items = this.state.itemsAgregados.slice();
        if(!items.indexOf(data.id_producto)){
            console.log("no se encuentra");
            items.push(id);
            this.setState({
                'itemsAgregados':items
            });

        }else{
            console.log("ya existe");
            item.removerSeleccion();
        }
        console.log("registrando items",id);
    }
 render() {
        return (
            <div className="content-app">
                <Navbar data={this.menu}/>
                <div className="container lista-productos">
                    {
                        this.state.productos.map((producto, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Item data={producto}
                                      registro = {this.registrarItems}
                                      key={producto.id_producto}/>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

And Item.jsx:

```
 render() {

        let props = this.props;
        let img = JSON.parse(props.data.imagen);
        let imgPath = Rutas.apiStatic + 'img/productos/' + props.data.id_producto + '/' + img.sm;
        props.data.items  = this;

        return (
            <div className="row item-listado">
                <div className="col-xs-3">
                    <img src={imgPath} className="img-circle img-item"/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-7">
                    <Link to={Rutas.producto + props.data.identificador}>
                        <h3 className="titulo">{props.data.titulo}</h3>
                        <span className="price">$ {props.data.precio}</span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-2 text-right">
                    <ul className="list-unstyled list-acciones">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" onClick={()=>props.registro(props.data,this)} className={this.state.classAdd}>
                                <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

As you can see, I pass the "registrarItems" method as a param to Item and there, i add this as onClick event in the  tag from item. But I need pass the "data" and the own "item" element to the onclick function. The first, for save the element clicked in the Items array, or remove it (if it already exists) because the button may have a toggle function. But in my "console.log" **both params passed on the onClick method with the arrow function** shows as "undefined".
I saw some examples and i don't get my error. can anybody helpme? thanks.

Comment: try binding `registrarItems` to the class `List` inside `constructor` or define `registarItems` as a class property (provided you've [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) presets) using arrow function.

Comment: The thing is that if i put that method as a property, i lost the access to PArent class. I tried it and I tray create it as a callback method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solve for this was simple. I resolved it with something similar as **Free-soul** said on his comment.

First, I passed the List Component as a param to item. Below my code in List's render method:

```
{
        this.state.productos.map((producto, index) => {
            this.items[producto.id_producto] = producto;
            return (
                <Item data={producto}

                      parent = {this}
                      key={producto.id_producto}/>
            );
        })
    }
```

Then I get the parent param in *componentDidMount* method and later I call the *validarItem* function directly from the List method and I pass the params that i need.
Here my Item code:

```
onClickPlus(id,data) {

        //{Rutas.listas + 'productos/' + props.data.id_producto //Url para pasar uno solo
        this.setState({
            classAdd:'selected'
        })
        if(!this.state.parent.validarItem(this.state.data)){
            this.removerSeleccion()
        }
        if(this.state.seleccionMultiple){

        }
    }
    removerSeleccion(){

        this.setState({classAdd:'normal'})
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            parent: this.props.parent,
            data : this.props.data
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            // more code
                <a href="#" onClick={() => this.onClickPlus(parent)} className={this.state.classAdd}>
                    <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            //more render code...
        )
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best practice, but works for me.